# Anamalous pixels added after sending image via http

Tags: javascript, html, http, canvas

I have a function which generates a certain image and adds a anamolous 1px wide white line at x=0 spanning across the height of the image. I am manually snipping it away using canvas and i can confirm the image looks ok and without the extra pixels manually on the filesystem.E Even though writeFileSync is blocking i have added a 5 second delay to be "safe" but after rendering this new image on my html the anamolous 1px wide line is back and i am flabbergasted on how it came back. My best guestimate right now is during the transport from the backend to the frontend.

server,js

```
 const slide = SlideNumbers[data.cert]; 
  await certGenerator(data);
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
  if (slide <= 16) {
    console.log("Clipping 1px");
    const canvas = createCanvas(651, 887);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const image = await loadImage(`./certs/output${slide - 1}.png`);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 887); //snipping away 1 pixel wide line
    fs.writeFileSync(`./certs/output${slide - 1}.png`, canvas.toBuffer());
  }
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  res
    .status(200)
    .sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, `../certs/output${slide - 1}.png`));
```

and here is the html

```
   fetch("/update", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                          "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(data),
                      })
                        .then((response) => response.blob())
                        .then((imageBlob) => {
                          // Create a URL for the image blob
                          var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
                          // Create an <img> element
                          var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
                          console.log(imageUrl);

                          // Set the source of the image to the generated image
                          imgElement.src = imageUrl;

                          // Append the image element to the "imageContainer" div
                          document
                            .getElementById("imageContainer")
                            .appendChild(imgElement);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                          console.error("Error:", error);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 887)` doesn't reduce the size of the canvas, so try creating a smaller canvas in the first place, and draw the image to the canvas without copying the unwanted line. Something like

```
if (slide <= 16) {
    console.log("Clipping 1px");
    const canvas = createCanvas(650, 887); // 1px less in the x direction
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const image = await loadImage(`./certs/output${slide - 1}.png`);
    //snipping away 1 pixel wide line:
    ctx.drawImage(image, 1, 0, 650, 887, 0, 0, 650, 887 );
    
    fs.writeFileSync(`./certs/output${slide - 1}.png`, canvas.toBuffer());
  }
```

Documentation for the `drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)` form of the call is available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

If the server side implementation of `drawImage` is non conformant you may need to copy pixels from a 651 wide canvas to a separate 650 px wide one that you create.

Comment: Hahaha, I was near the solution during my research, i was trying to resize the entire element. Not sure why i didn't see that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: glad to have helped. Make sure you don't repeatedly overwrite the original `.png` sources every time the front end requests a slide as it will degrade the source. Also note that canvas buffers are not in `.png` format.